# Return a list of the largest file per ID from a list of file paths Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, path, operating-system

Let's say I have a list with file paths as strings as so:

`['/#path#/AAA_123444_10D', '/#path#/AAA_123444_11D', '/#path#/BBB_987666_12D', '/#path#/CCC_987666_15D', '/#path#/DDD_123444_18D']`

The IDs in each filename are the 6 digit numbers after the first underscore. I want to return a list of the file paths of the largest file **size** per ID. In this instance, lets say the file `/#path#/AAA_123444_11D` is the biggest of the files with ID 123444 and the file `/#path#/BBB_987666_12D` is the biggest on disk of the files with ID 987666. In this instance, I would want to return the following list:

`['/#path#/AAA_123444_11D', '/#path#/BBB_987666_12D']`

The list should contain only one of each ID. Order doesn't matter.

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: How do you decide which one it the largest file, do you look at the value after ID_ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
import os
import ntpath

# file selector
def multipleFileSelector(Title='Choose Files'):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title=Title)
    root.destroy()
    filelist_Path = root.tk.splitlist(filepath)
    return filelist_Path

# checks if ID exists in the list already or not
def idListCheck(comp, lst):
    for path in lst:
        if ntpath.basename(path).split('_')[2] == comp:
            return True
    return False

# Problem really starts here
filelist_Path = list(multipleFileSelector())

sorted_filelist = []
for path in filelist_Path:
    print(ntpath.basename(path).split('_')[2])
    lst = [i for i, e in enumerate(filelist_Path) if ntpath.basename(e).split('_')[2] == ntpath.basename(path).split('_')[2]]
    if lst and not idListCheck(ntpath.basename(path).split('_')[2], sorted_filelist):
        biggest_file = [-1,0] # -1 is arbitrary
        for same_id_index in lst:
            size_of_file = os.path.getsize(filelist_Path[same_id_index])
            if size_of_file > biggest_file[1]:
                biggest_file = [same_id_index, size_of_file]
        sorted_filelist.append(filelist_Path[biggest_file[0]])

print(sorted_filelist)
```